# format painter is not changing font family in MS-Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have one MS-Word document of multiple pages. I have Century fonts in some pages and Times New Roman in some pages and I want to change the Times New Roman to Cetury by Format Painter tool of MS-Word along with other formatting (font size, weight, style etc). All is working well except the font is not changing from Times New Roman to Century.

Is there any settings that is preventing Format Painter in changing the font family or changing the font family is not actually possible by Format Painter tool?

Comment: Format Painter is supposed to copy the Font and I just tested it on my system with the Fonts you mention, and it works fine. What version of Word are you using and is it fully updated?

Comment: Rich Michaels' experience mirrors my own, which is why I gave you alternative methods. If my answer does not meet your needs, please provide more information. Perhaps save a sample document with the problem on DropBox or OneDrive and include a view link with your question as well as answer Rich's questions. If my answer does meet your needs, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I did not come online for the last couple of days. Yes, I can see it is ok now. Very weird, why that did not work previously! Anyhow, if the problem again arises in future, I will let you know. Thank you very much for yours valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is better handled at the beginning by using Styles for formatting rather than direct formatting. Here is my page on Styles. [Importance of Styles in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview) However, you have the situation you have, now.

### I would use the Replace function in Word to handle this task.

Replace can be reached using the keyboard shortcut of **Ctrl+H** or selecting it in the dropdown from the Find/Navigation pane.

Click on the **More button** at the bottom left of the dialog.

[image: screenshot of Replace dialog]

Then, with the insertion point in the Find What box, click on Format > Font and pick Times New Roman.

[image: Screenshot showing Format > Font]

Then, click in the Replace box and do the same thing for Century.

[image: Screenshot with formatting showing]

Then click the Replace All button.